# Can one derive the Schrödinger equation from probability density arguments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

My interest is regarding a probability amplitude $\psi^\dagger \psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0,\infty)$, where $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. The average position is

$$
\bar{x}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x (\psi (x,t))^\dagger \psi(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}
$$

and the average velocity is:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} \bar{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x (\psi (x,t))^\dagger \psi(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{2}
$$

yielding an equation of motion.

Since the Schrödinger equation is the equation of motion of quantum mechanics, how can I get to it form (2)? Is it even possible?

Comment: Careful, $\psi^\dagger\psi$ doesn't map into $[0,1]$. The integral over all of it is $1$, but since $|\psi|^2$ is just a density, not an actual probability, it is possible for $|\psi|^2 > 1$ while the integral still is $1$. To check, just look at the harmonic oscillator solution and use large values of $\omega$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator

Comment: Mathematical rigor aside, have you tried pulling the derivative into the integral and inserting Schrödinger's equation for $\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger$?

Comment: @TBissinger Yes plenty of times, but I am trying to derive the Schrodinger's equation. If I insert it to derive it, then it defeats the purpose!

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread. You want to know how to derive Schrödingers equation from (2), right? That is not possible, I think. (2) contains less information than the Schrödinger equation. Maybe like deriving the Maxwell equation from the wave equation.

Comment: Why do you think the second derivative in (2) gives you the average velocity?

Comment: Why are you writing $\psi^\dagger$ rather than $\psi^*$?

Comment: A second derivative is $d^2/dt^2$, not $d^2/d^2t$.

Comment: @TBissinger Since one can integrate over an arbitrarily small interval $P=\int_a^b \psi^*\psi dx$ and such interval must still yield a probability, then I would think it follows that $\psi^*\psi$ must be in $[0,1]$ for any interval of integration, no?

Comment: @TBissinger Actually, I think I get your point with the probability density. I can just think of the Dirac delta which is "infinity" at one point and zero elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay I'm afraid no. Consider a Gaussian $p(x) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$. This is a probability density and it is normalized, but for $\sigma^2 < 1/2\pi$, its value at zero is $p(0) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} > 0$.

Comment: Ah, perfect :) Very well then. Please also consider G. Smith's comments.

Comment: @G.Smith Well, the second derivate would in fact be the average acceleration.

Comment: But that’s not what you wrote.

Comment: @TBissinger Did you mean to write $p(0)>1$?

Comment: Your EOM only bounds the motion of the average position. It doesn't define the evolution of the entire PDF.

Comment: @G. Smith Indeed. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations you have written down are general definitions for the average position of a quantum particle and its derivatives. They apply to any single particle system and don't draw any kind of distinction between them.

The Schrödinger equation, however contains a potential term, which contains information about the forces acting on a particle in that specific situation. This information is not present in anything you have written down, so the Schrödinger equation cannot be derived without additional information.

This additional information can be provided in the form of [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem), which is equivalent to the Shrödinger equation.

Comment: Can explain what is and how using Stone's theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#Derivation_of_the_Schrödinger_equation_from_the_Ehrenfest_theorems allows them to get $\hat{H}$ from the above line?

Comment: Stone's Theorem states that $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle = G |\psi\rangle$ for some operator $G$. The rest of the proof is showing that this $G = \frac{p^2}{2m}+V = H$